# Foreach on Json based on value

Tags: c#, json, list

Please, how can write a `Foreach` of this json in C#:

```
{   "tabla": [
    {
      "nombretabla": "TABLE1",
      "campostabla": {
        "campo": [
          "FIELD1",
          "FIELD2"
        ]
      },
      "filtro": "FIELD1=100"
    },
    {
      "nombretabla": "TABLE2",
      "campostabla": {
        "campo": [
          "FIELD1",
          "FIELD2",
          "FIELD3"
        ]
      },
      "filtro": "FIELD2=200"
    }

  ] }
```

for extract values of each `tabla` element and extract values on `campo` element for a final results on separated lists like:

New List 1 (values of `tabla` = `TABLE1`):

```
FIELD1
FIELD2
```

New List 2 (values of `tabla` = `TABLE2`):

```
FIELD1
FIELD2
FIELD3
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should post your C# code processing the JSON.

Comment: I tried a simple Foreach but I can't set a "breakdown" for value changes of "tabla" element into the Foreach. (a check of a new value of "tabla" for init populating of a new list).

Comment: We don't know if you've already parsed the JSON, what kind of data structure you've parsed it into, etc. It's really hard to help you without seeing the context of your problem.

Comment: You cant iterate JSON as is - it is serializer output (Google it).  So, first you need to parse it or deserialize it.  Many hundreds of posts here on how to do either one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a crude example, that uses the `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package, you can work from and use as inspiration perhaps. It groups by table name and then gets the list for each one. You may want to do it differently I'm not sure.

```
var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<root>(json);
var groups = o.tabla.GroupBy(t => t.nombretabla);

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    var tableName = group.Key;

    var tabla = group.FirstOrDefault();
    if (tabla != null)
    {
        var list = tabla.campostabla.campo.ToList();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Boiler plate classes that you should change as required...

```
public class root
{
    public Tabla[] tabla { get; set; }
}

public class Tabla
{
    public string nombretabla { get; set; }
    public CamposTabla campostabla { get; set; }
    public string filtro { get; set; }
}

public class CamposTabla
{
    public string[] campo { get; set; }
}
```